# IPTABLE block access to an URI over HTTPS?

Tags: iptables

I am working on a project and one of the tests requires some parts of the website to be unreachable to see how the website reacts and which message description is provided when there is an error.

my website is on port 7002 and uses HTTPS. The unreachable part will be defined as test

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "test" --destination-port 7002 --algo kmp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

This should work. My issue here is that HTTPS encrypts everything and makes the server unable to see when a network device is requesting test URI so it is never activated

The following line works but takes the whole website down which means the error messages are about the whole site being down:

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 7002 -j DROP
```

Is there any way of making `-m string --string "test"` work over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way of making -m string --string "test" work over HTTPS?

No, and that's kind of *the whole point* of HTTPS. The firewall may be able to match the domain names (due to SNI) but it will never see the paths.

However, it does not really make much sense for different paths at the same domain to have different reachability, because the path is only transferred *after* the server has been successfully reached (TCP and TLS handshakes successfully made).

I think your test would be more realistic either if the blocked part of the website was indeed on a different domain (or port), or if you made it return HTTP-level failure codes (e.g. 50x) instead of just quietly dropping the request.

For example, you could set up Apache or Nginx to pretend that it's the API server, then you could configure it to return error 503 for certain URLs but reverse-proxy everything else to the real server.